# EF can't get the reference entity of navigation property of an entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

This is my model classes

```
public class Serve
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Table Table { get; set; }
    public bool IsFinished { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalMoney { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public int Numbers { get; set; }
    public bool IsCheifReceived { get; set; }
    public bool IsCheifCooked { get; set; }
    public Serve Serve { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
        IsCheifCooked = IsCheifReceived = false;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }    
    public Category Category { get; set; }    
    public bool IsNeedToNotifyChief { get; set; }
}
```

I want to sum the Number and total money of Orders grouped by same Item (This is the Menu Item of the restaurant).

This is the LINQ query.

```
var serving = db.Serves
                    .Where(m => m.Table.Id == table.Id)
                    .Where(m => m.IsFinished == false)
                    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

var groupedOrder = serving.Orders
                        .OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
                        .GroupBy(m => m.Item)
                        .Select(g => new
                        {
                            Item = g.Key,
                            Numbers = g.Sum(ri => ri.Numbers)
                        }).ToList();
```

But in this case, in `.GroupBy(m => m.Item)` the `m.Item` is `null`, and it grouped all the Orders to one group. (I know the problem is the `m.Item` is not loaded in this Query)

Here, I don't know how to make the m.Item is loaded in this LINQ Query.
Please help me to do this.

P.S.: I use Entity Framework 6

Comment: Object of `Serving` class mentioned above.

Comment: Where are you initializing `Orders`?

Comment: @X-TECH i don't ask about class `Serving`, I ask about `serving` variable

Comment: @Back I said, it is `object` of Serving and I don't know where he initialized it.

Comment: right btn click on 'serving' -> 'Go To Definition' will help you to find that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the variable **serving** is list of some objects, not a query. If I'm right, you should to include **items** when you getting **serving** from DB. It will be look like code below:

```
var serving = db.Serves
                 .Include(x => x.Orders)
                 .Include(x => x.Orders.Select(x => x.Item)) //here you'll get your items
                 .Where(m => m.Table.Id == ta && m.IsFinished == false)
                 .OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
                 .FirstOfDefault();

//and after that your code should work correctly

if(serving != null) //don't forget check it, if you use FirstOfDefault()
{
   var groupedOrder = serving.Orders
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
            .GroupBy(m => m.Item) 
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Item = g.Key,
                Numbers = g.Sum(ri => ri.Numbers)
            }).ToList();
}
```